# NLog stops functioning after a while

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm using NLog 4.2.2 in a .NET 4.5 C# project on Windows.

After a while (e.g. 12 hours), NLog stops writing messages to the log files. If I enable CLR exceptions, I get the following exception whenever the code invokes NLog to emit a message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace.
```

The stacktrace only mentions `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)`.

Here is the NLog configuration file I'm using: https://gist.github.com/dictoon/2cb39c9d1da52a651ac3

Did anyone ever witness this?

Comment: You are trying to create a folder, while not giving it a legit name?

Comment: I'm not trying to create a folder. NLog is somehow calling `CreateDirectory()`, not my code.

Comment: what kind of application (Windows UI/command line executable, service or web site) is this?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Good point. It's a command line executable.

Comment: so this executable runs for 12 hours straight? Memory issues? Or is it started on a regular basis? What makes NLog to work "again" after it started failing?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Yes, it's meant to run for rather long times. No memory issues as far as I can tell. I'm actually logging memory statistics via NLog, the last report indicates 198 MB of private memory, 232 MB of working set. Also, in the last few hours the program wasn't doing anything, just periodically reporting its health. What makes it "work again" is usually just restarting the program, which I just did, and for the first time I got the exact same error on startup. I played a bit with the config file and now it's working again, even after I reverted all changes made to the config file...

Comment: Strange. I see you already opened a thread on the NLog support forums, maybe it is an NLog bug. I don't see anything wrong with your config file at least.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek One way or another, I think it's a NLog bug. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: Update: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NLog developers have confirmed this to be an NLog bug: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1120

Comment: To be precise, this isn't a bug but a config mistake (with a not so good error message). TL;DR: you need `${basedir}` for relative paths. The need for  `${basedir}` will be removed in NLog 4.3